# Share settings between a group of Backbone.js models/views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am working on a UI, using Backbone + Marionette.js, which displays the same Widget multiple times on a single page. I am struggling with whats the best way to contain events inside each widget. Lets say each widget displays a selected friend's Facebook information (interests, status feed, mutual friends). If the user changes the selected friend for that specific widget what would be the best way to update the models that are part of that widget?

Here is how I am thinking of solving this ...

Create Setting Model - when user selects a different friend inside a widget the Friend select view updates the Setting model.

Approach 1: 
Controller listens to the setting model on "change" events and in turn updates all the relevant models. Each model will never know of the setting model.

Approach 2:
Pass setting model to each Model's options and each model listen's to the setting model and when it changes it does whatever it needs to (reload, etc).

These are the 2 approaches that come to my mind. I feel like I am liking the Approach 1 better, but I would appreciate any feedback from people that have used Backbone in a similar fashion.

Thanks,
Habeel

Answer (score 0):

I would go for approach 2 using a singleton setting model as you suggested. That way the views or models listening to the settings are responsible for doing the updating. Approach 1 has two potential pitfalls. If you move the logic of what actually happens to the controller, it can become convoluted and complex. If the controller just reacts to change events on the settings model and propagate them to other models and views, then there seem to be little reason for it to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to make use of Marionette's [event aggregator](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#appvent-event-aggregator) feature. This would allow you to not even need a settings model. Instead, just have the changed model fire a global event that the other models are listening for and adjust accordingly.